# how to animate the deg attribute in jquery

Tags: jquery

Consider the following css

```
.meter .arrow,.banner2 .meter .arrow {-moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
```

i would like to animate from 0deg to 8deg over a few seconds.

Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers you're targeting with those CSS rules support CSS transitions. Add a class in CSS for the rotated state, and give the div a transition rule: http://jsfiddle.net/4JK7q/.

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s linear;
```